# Set to none suspicious operation RequestDataTooBig

Tags: django

I did found this piece of documentation on django doc :

The maximum size in bytes that a request body may be before a SuspiciousOperation (RequestDataTooBig) is raised. The check is done when accessing request.body or request.POST and is calculated against the total request size excluding any file upload data. ***You can set this to None to disable the check***. Applications that are expected to receive unusually large form posts should tune this setting.

But I don't know how to disable that check , the error that I get is :

```
Request body exceeded settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE.
Request body exceeded settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE.
Request body exceeded settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE.
Request body exceeded settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE.
Request body exceeded settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE.
Request body exceeded settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE.
Request body exceeded settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE.
Request body exceeded settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = None` inside the `settings.py`. But setting it `None` could lead to security vulnerabilities!

Comment: Thanks I did it and it s working fine but how can I do it in a security protected way ?

Comment: You should set it to a resonable value that fits your needs instead of deactivated this mechanism. Here you can find some information about hardening django apps https://substance.brpx.com/hardening-django-one-dos-at-a-time-30bbfc8c853#.hgjsvjfa6